# Setting up default overwritable constructors and destructors or other functions for a set of commands

Tags: bash

```
alias cmd_name="source mainshell cmd_name"
```

My plan is to alias a single main script to a set of script names. Now on invocation of any script that main script would be called and it can define certain functions or constructors and destructor. Then it can check that script file if it has a constructor definition. If it has one, call that constructor else call the default one. Then source that script and then call the destructor. This would also give that script access to the default functions setup by main script. This shall work fine but these aliases can’t be exported to subshells.

To add to that, I just want these defaults functions available to that particular aliased set of commands and want those functions to destroy once command execution is complete. That’s why I can’t just write them on `.bash_profile` making it absolutely global.

```
command_name() {
# initial code
source path/to/command_name
# destructing code
}
```

Another option which I found was to create function for each name and call my script inside. This one is exportable too. In this way i could just encapsulate every command in a function with same name and can easily have initial codes and destroying code. Here the problem is that i can’t define any more functions inside that function and it would get really clumsy too doing everything inside a function.

Another thought I had was symbolic links, but they seem to have a limit to how many I can create to a particular script.

What should be the best way to achieve this or if its somehow an inappropriate design, can someone please explain?

Comment: What is a "single main shell"? What is "main shell"? What exactly are you trying to do? What is a "main command file"? What does a "default constructor" do? Why do you need constructors and destructors concept in bash in the first place?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have a set of scripts and i want to create more. I want each one of them to execute certain code before their execution and just before they die I want to remove that code made available for them through the destructor. The simple reason i want this constructor and destructor concept is that i want to do quite a lot of common settings for all those scripts and want to remove those settings once they ends. And these scripts are to be called by `source` so they do effect the parent shell that called them

Comment: `just before they die` - what does it mean to die? Before script termination? `remove that code` - you want to delete the script? Or, like, you create a temporary file in "constructor" and want to auto-delete this temporary file with script execution termination in something you call "destructor"? It would help a lot, if you would give examples of those "constructors" and "destructors" and example of such a script.

Comment: Aliasing functions in bash is a bad idea and leads to unreadable scripts. Choose meaningful, concise and descriptive function names and stick with that. If you need some type of "pointer" behavior, bash is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you're trying to achieve the following:

- A set of commands that necessarily take place in the context of the current shell rather than a new shell process.
- These commands have a lot of common functionality that needs to be factored out of these commands.
- The common functionality must not be accessible to the current shell.

In that case, the common code would be e.g. functions & variables that you have to explicitly unset after the command has been executed. Therefore, your best bet is to have a function per-command, have that function source the common code, and have the common code also have another function (called before you return) to unset everything.

Notes:

- You can actually declare functions inside other functions, but the nested functions will actually be global - so name them uniquely and don't forget to unset them.
- If they don't need to affect the current shell then you can just put them in their own file, source the common code, and not unset anything.
- There is generally no limit to how many symlinks you can create to a single file. The limit on symlink chains (symlink to symlink to symlink etc.) is low.